# Java String For Loop not reading if statement

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I was wondering why this isn't working? I've been looking at it for a while, wondering why it doesn't work. It doesn't seem to be reading the if statement. Everything looks right to me, even when you put in a legal string like "A5".

```
    System.out.println("PLEASE TYPE IN A COORDINATE, LETTER FIRST, THEN NUMBER.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("CAPITALS ONLY, PLEASE. ENTER COORDINATE HERE: ");

    String placement = scan.next();
    String letter = placement.substring(0,1);
    String number = placement.substring(1);

    System.out.println(letter);
    //System.out.println(placement);
    System.out.println(number);

    String cord[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};

    for(int s = 0; s < cord.length; s++)
    {
        //System.out.println(cord[s]);
        if(cord[s] == letter)
        {
            System.out.print("yay, it worked");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Common mistake: `String/Object` comparison should use `equals()` instead of `==` (except String literal comparison).

```
if(cord[s] == letter)
```

should be

```
if(letter.equals(cords[s]))
```

`equals()` compares object content equality. `==` compares reference equality.

Comment: In general, you should compare Objects using `equals()`, not `==`. (This is for the OP, not the answerer.)

Comment: another question: what if the array is filled with integers instead of the string, same thing?

Comment: @RobertHartley: If array is int (primitive type) array then use ==. You can't call equals() on primitive types, it will be compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

`letter` is a `String` object. In your loop, `cord[s]` is also a `String` object. But they are two *different* objects.

Writing `letter == cord[s]` does not compare values, it compares the *references*. You need to use `.equals()` to compare values, ie write `letter.equals(cord[s])`.

See javadoc on Object, and in particular `.equals()`/`.hashCode()`.